In Bereshit 1:1, does בָּרָא suggest "made out of nothing" or simply "gave a form to"?
Disclaimer: I don't know Hebrew.
In Bereshit 1:1, does בָּרָא suggest "made out of nothing" or simply "gave a form to"? I have heard it suggested that it implies "creation out of nothing," and English supports both senses, however, the context doesn't seem to allow the "out of nothing" idea, since Adam, for example, was "formed" from the clay.

Commentaries say the latter is referring to the creation of his soul.

In the context, a "soul" is simply a "breather"/"living person," is it not? How might a "soul" in the sense of a "sentient component" get created out of both nothing and clay?

No, the soul is a distinct spiritual entity which animates matter but is not composed of matter. See Genesis 2:7.

https://rabbibenherman.com/2015/10/10/three-types-of-creation/

So in your view, the breath of life was not the animus of Adam/Clay, nor was his animus formed from the clay, but his animus (and that of the birds, animalia and sea creatures) were spoken into existence (despite no such assertion in the text, and contrary to the explicit assertions in the text)? I find the claim to be entirely eisegetical.

It literally says He breathed a soul into him. But you can call it a breath of life. I'm not sure what distinction you're trying to make.

May I ask you what lexicon agrees that ruach means "soul"? Which translation refers to ruach as "soul"?

It says nishmas. Where do you see ruach? (Btw, I won't get notified without a tag because there are other commenters in this thread.)

Sorry, @shmosel, so...
May I ask you what lexicon agrees that nishmas means "soul"? Which translation refers to nishmas as "soul"?

It's basic Hebrew. נשמת is the construct state of נשמה, soul. It's closely related to the word for breath, maybe even synonymous in biblical Hebrew, but I don't think it changes the connotation that G-d introduced something into Adam which brought him to life.

@shmosel, Yes, breath. It makes no sense to breathe souls, or to breathe a soul into a person. Not to me, anyway.

The OP refers to B'reishit 1:1 which is the creation of the world not the creation of Adam HaRishon

@EdwardB, more specifically it refers to two specific things: The sky reservoir and the dry land that was exposed by the gathering of the remaining waters into an ocean. Most, if not everything, was formed from preexistent material.

Forming from dust is referring to the body. Man is a body and a soul, and that is mentioned in in 1:27 with creating rather than forming

@RabbiKaii, as I read it, when the LORD breathed into man the breath of life, he "became" a living soul. He doesn't "have" a soul, but "is" a "soul"/"breather." IE: "a living being." Confusion is treating two or more different things as identical. Breath of life and נֶפֶשׁ are two different things. Think of a light bulb. The electricity passes thru the wire in the same way the breath of life animates the body. The lit bulb is the soul. When the breath leaves, the soul/light goes out, the body returns to dust. Some say the breath returns to God.

@Ruminator what has that got to do with your question, sorry?

@RabbiKaii, whether Bereshit "means" creation out of nothing or just giving form to something is the very germ of my question.

@Ruminator and how does that pertain to your analysis about the difference between a lightbulb and the electricity, etc

@RabbiKaii, Moses describes two components of a man: his body and his breath. Combined, they are a soul/breather. It is akin to a light bulb which has two components: the physical bulb, the energy coursing through it, but the soul is the whole package: physical bulb + applied energy = a "living bulb."

...........and?

@RabbiKaii, Sorry, I have other matters to attend to. Perhaps it will click after some consideration. Thank you for your responses.

The dust have formed from nothing, then Adam was formed from the dust

@Coreofreality, doesn't Genesis describe the making of the "dry land" as simply the LORD separating the preexistent water into above and below and gathering the remaining waters into an ocean, thus revealing the dry land below? Elsewhere, such as Ps 24:1-2, he is said to have put the dry land on unexplainable foundations, onto the abyss:
24 Of David. A psalm.
  The earth is the LORD’s and all that it holds, 
     the world and its inhabitants. 
  2For He founded it upon the ocean, 
     set it on the nether-streams. 

Jewish Publication Society. (1985).

@Ruminator no. Rashi said everything was created on the first day from absolutely nothing. Nothing existed before at all. Throughout the other days he simply placed the creations in their correct locations

@Coreofreality, I was thinking more about what Moses said.

@Ruminator Moses said to listen to rashi

@Coreofreality, Eh?

B"H
Ramban to Bereishis 1:1 explicitly says that the word "Bara" is the only word that can be used in the Hebrew language to describe creation from complete and absolute nothing, and that at first Hashem created the "initial matter", and all other creations were only "formed" from that matter.

הקב"ה ברא כל הנבראים מאפיסה מוחלטת. ואין אצלנו בלשון הקדש בהוצאת היש
מאין אלא לשון "ברא"; ואין כל ה"נעשה" – תחת השמש או למעלה – הווה מן
האין התחלה ראשונה. אבל הוציא מן האפס הגמור המוחלט יסוד דק מאד, אין בו
ממש, אבל הוא כוח ממציא, מוכן לקבל הצורה ולצאת מן הכוח אל הפועל. והוא
החומר הראשון, נקרא ליוונים "היולי". ואחר ההיולי לא ברא דבר, אבל יצר
ועשה, כי ממנו המציא הכל והלביש הצורות ותיקן אותן.
The Holy One, Blessed be He, created all creations from absolute
nothingness. In our Holy Tongue, there is no term for bringing
existence out of nothingness other than the term "bara" (created). And
nothing that is made—whether under the sun or above—comes into being
from nothing as a first beginning. Rather, He brought forth from
complete and absolute nothingness a very fine essence, which has no
substance but is a generative force, ready to receive form and
transition from potential to actual. This is the primordial matter,
known to the Greeks as "hyle." After the creation of the hyle, He did
not create anything anew, but rather formed and made, for from it He
brought forth everything, clothed them in forms, and perfected them.


The Ramban to Genesis 1:26 addresses this question. I have copied both the Hebrew text and its translation from Sefaria for reference:

וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים נַעֲשֶׂה אָדָם נתייחד בעשיית האדם מאמר בעבור גודל
מעלתו כי אין טבעו כטבע החיה והבהמה אשר ברא במאמר הקודם לו והפשט הנכון
במלת "נַעֲשֶׂה" הוא מפני שכבר הראית לדעת (רמב"ן על בראשית א׳:א׳) כי
האלהים בָּרָא יש מאין ביום הראשון לבדו ואחר כך מן היסודות ההם הנבראים
יצר ועשה וכאשר נתן במים כח השרוץ לשרוץ נפש חיה והיה המאמר בהם
"יִשְׁרְצוּ הַמַּיִם" (בראשית א׳:כ׳) והיה המאמר בבהמה "תּוֹצֵא הָאָרֶץ"
(בראשית א׳:כ״ד) אמר באדם "נַעֲשֶׂה" כלומר אני והארץ הנזכרת נַעֲשֶׂה
אָדָם שתוציא הארץ הגוף מיסודיה כאשר עשתה בבהמה ובחיה כדכתיב (בראשית
ב׳:ז׳) וַיִּיצֶר ה' אֱלֹהִים אֶת הָאָדָם עָפָר מִן הָאֲדָמָה ויתן הוא
יתברך הרוח מפי עליון כדכתיב (שם) וַיִּפַּח בְּאַפָּיו נִשְׁמַת חַיִּים
ואמר "בְּצַלְמֵנוּ כִּדְמוּתֵנוּ" כי ידמה לשניהם במתכונת גופו לארץ אשר
לוקח ממנה וידמה ברוח לעליונים שאינה גוף ולא תמות ואמר בכתוב השני
בְּצֶלֶם אֱלֹהִים בָּרָא אֹתוֹ (בראשית א׳:כ״ז) לספר הפלא אשר נפלא בו
משאר הנבראים וזה פשט המקרא הזה מצאתיו לרבי יוסף הקמחי והוא הנראה מכל
מה שחשבו בו ופירוש "צֶלֶם" כמו תאר וּצְלֵם אַנְפּוֹהִי אֶשְׁתַּנִּי (דניאל
ג יט) וכן אַךְ בְּצֶלֶם יִתְהַלֶּךְ אִישׁ (תהלים לט ז) בָּעִיר צַלְמָם
תִּבְזֶה (תהלים עג כ) תאר מראיתו ו"דמות" הוא דמיון בצורה ובמעשה כי
הקרובים בענין יקראו דומים זה לזה והנה האדם דומה לתחתונים ולעליונים
בתאר והדר כדכתיב (תהלים ח ו) וְכָבוֹד וְהָדָר תְּעַטְּרֵהוּ והוא מגמת
פניו בחכמה ובדעת וכשרון המעשה ובדמות ממש שידמה גופו לעפר ונפשו
לעליונים:
AND G-D SAID: ‘LET US MAKE MAN.’ There was a special command dedicated
to the making of man because of his great superiority since his nature
is unlike that of beasts and cattle which were created with the
preceding command. The correct explanation of na’aseh (let us make)
[which is in the plural form when it should have been in the singular]
is as follows: It has been shown to you that G-d created something
from nothing only on the first day, and afterwards He formed and made
things from those created elements. Thus when He gave the waters the
power of bringing forth a living soul, the command concerning them was
Let the waters swarm. The command concerning cattle was Let the earth
bring forth. But in the case of man He said, Let us make, that is, I
and the aforementioned earth, let us make man, the earth to bring
forth the body from its elements as it did with cattle and beasts, as
it is written, And the Eternal G-d formed man of the dust of the
ground, and He, blessed be He, to give the spirit from His mouth, the
Supreme One, as it is written, And He breathed into his nostrils the
breath of life. And He said, In our image, and after our likeness, as
man will then be similar to both. In the capacity of his body, he will
be similar to the earth from which he was taken, and in spirit he will
be similar to the higher beings, because it [the spirit] is not a body
and will not die. In the second verse, He says, In the image of G-d He
created him, in order to relate the distinction by which man is
distinguished from the rest of created beings. The explanation of this
verse I have found ascribed to Rabbi Joseph the Kimchite, and is the
most acceptable of all interpretations that have been advanced
concerning it. The meaning of tzelem is as the word to’ar
(appearance), as in ‘Vetzelem’ (And the appearance) of his face was
changed; similarly, Surely ‘b’tzelem’ (as a mere appearance) man
walketh; When Thou arousest Thyself ‘tzalmam’ (their appearance) Thou
wilt despise, that is, the appearance of their countenance. And the
meaning of the word d’muth is similarity in form and deed, as things
that are akin in a certain matter are called similar to each other.
Thus man is similar both to the lower and higher beings in appearance
and honor, as it is written, And Thou hast crowned him with glory and
honor, meaning that the goal before him is wisdom, knowledge, and
skill of deed. In real likeness his body thus compares to the earth
while his soul is similar to the higher beings.

Also view Ramban to verse 21 where he explains why the great sea creatures also needed to be created from nought and not formed like the rest of creation.
To summarize, the Ramban seems to hold that ברא does mean create from nothing in all cases. However by man, there are two parts - the soul was created from nothing while the body was formed from the ground. This is unique to man because as the Ramban explains, man has a a soul above all other creations which is why it did not need to state ברא by any other creation (for the soul aspect). And it is not contradictory to the great sea creatures because their having being created from nothing was for their physical body (as Ramban explains why specifically them and not all other creations), while man’s having being created from nothing is for the soul, whereas the body of man was formed from the ground.

Why can't you say that the dust and water, from which the other creations were made, was from nothing, but the creatures themselves were created from pre made material?
